# how to chose between two implementation code in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have uploaded the very small exemple project on a [github repository](https://github.com/Et7f3/question_on_stackoverflow)

I have a school project. The specifications say that we can enable or disable a component.

I came from the c world in which we can compile c to object and chose the object to link. I try this in OCaml.

I have two source file with the same function but their effect is different.
I have two folders called "on" with implementation and "off" folder with an empty body

For the test, I have a simple a.ml and a.mli file that only print hello world and b.mli b.ml that call the module a. (so I have on/a.ml and off/a.ml)

I compile the on version and the off with this command:

```
ocamlc -c -I on on/a.mli on/a.ml -o on/a.cmo
```

then I try to link the C-way

```
ocamlc on/a.cmo  b.ml -o on_b.exe
```

but I get the error

```
File "b.ml", line 1, characters 9-15:
Error: Unbound module A
```

I have then read I should specify the folder to search in with -I.

```
ocamlc -I on -I off on/a.cmo  b.ml -o on_b.exe
```

I was happy because of that work for the on version

but it will not work for the off version

```
ocamlc -I on -I off off/a.cmo b.ml -o off_b.exe
```

I get the error

```
Error: Files b.cmo and off/a.cmo
       make inconsistent assumptions over interface A
```

I have inspected with ocamlobjinfo it seems to build B its searches for the first module called A

In this example, I have only A and B but in future, I will build with some version on and some off... but don't do it manually

A solution found but no really efficient is to clean all .cmo and .cmi files ...

thanks for your reading and your time

EDIT:

I have also test with -open but it seems to work only for standards modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, compiling your `.mli` files produces a `.cmi` file. This is the file that you indicate is there by using the `-I dir` option.

So, if I understand you correctly, you have a `a.mli` in both your `on` and your `off` directory.

Now, when you refer to the module `A` in your code, the compiler looks for it in the current directory, then in the linked directories **in the order they are given**. When you compile "on", the right .cmi is found (because `-I on` comes before `-I off` in your command line). In the case of "off", the "on" cmi is found, and the compiler sees that it doesn't correspond to the right cmo.

Your two compiling lines should be:

```
ocamlc -I on on/a.cmo  b.ml -o on_b.exe
ocamlc -I off off/a.cmo  b.ml -o off_b.exe
```

Comment: I agree with you but in fact it's a exemple. In the future I would be able to pick the "on" version of a module A and the "off" version of a Module C and link with b.ml (the file that contain the main program)

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my answer but this is bad practice. Maybe you could give your on and off modules different names and make an aliasing file. For more complex needs you should probably use functors. Could you expand your question to tell us exactly what you need?

Comment: what is a aliasing file ?

Comment: A file that you would generate that would look like `module A = A_on module B = B_off` and so on.

Comment: Ok I will take this idea but if you have another solution that does not require to write such file. I'm here. I search for the linker name in OCaml.